# how to get column number by cell value in python using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am completely new to openpyxl and python and I am having a hard time with this issue and i need your help.

```
JAN FEB MAR MAR YTD 2019 YTD
25   9  57     23           7
61  41  29     5           57
54  34  58    10            7
13  13  63    26           45
31  71  40    40           40
24  38  63    63           47
31  50  43    2            61
68  33  13    9            63
28  1   30    39           71
```

I have an excel report with the data above. I'd like to search cells for those that contain a specific string (i.e., YTD) and get the column number for YTD column. I want to use the column number to extract data for that column. I do not want to use row and cell reference as the excel file gets updated regularly, thus d column will always move.

```py
def t_PM(ff_sheet1,start_row):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='report')  # open report
    report_sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet 1')

    col = -1
    for j, keyword in enumerate(report_sheet1.values(0)):
        if keyword=='YTD':
            col = j
            break      
    ff_sheet1.cell(row=insert_col + start_row, column= header['YTD_OT'], value=report_sheet1.cell(row=i + 7, column=col).value)
```

But then, I get an " 'generator' object is not callable" error. How can i fix this?

Comment: Would it not be easier to use Pandas?

Comment: I can't see a generator object?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace for the error message?

Comment: `report_sheet1.values` is a generator per the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.values).

Comment: try: `for j, keyword in enumerate(list(report_sheet1.values)[0])`.

Comment: @David Zemens , i tried that and the codes runs without error, but then it returns null values

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `report_sheet1.values` is a generator so you **can't** call it with `(0)`. I'm assuming by your code that you don't want to rely that the "YTD" will appear in the first row so you iterate all cells. Do this by:

```py
def find_YTD():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='report')  # open report
    report_sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet 1')

    for col in report_sheet1.iter_cols(values_only=True):
        for value in col:
            if isinstance(value, str) and 'YTD' in value:
                return col
```

---

If you **are** assuming this data will be in the first row, simply do:

```py
for cell in report_sheet1[1]:
    if isinstance(value, str) and 'YTD' in cell.value:
        return cell.column
```

- `openpyxl` uses '1-based' line indexing

Read the docs - [access many cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells)

Comment: I think the `(0)` in OP suggests an expectation that "YTD" will always appear in the first row.

Comment: `ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1)`

Comment: @Charlie Clark that's the same as doing `ws[1]`

Comment: You don't say? ;-) Works also with `iter_cols()` and it's worth spelling the general approach. It's worth noting than the question suggests columnar access but actually is just looking at the first row.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Thank you, I tried the code but then got this erro "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" based on this line of code "if 'YTD' in cell.value:"

Comment: I have added a check for empty cells. @Hass take a look

Comment: @Tomerikoo. I tried that too, then i get the following erro " argument of type 'float' is not iterable" for the line of code: "if value is not None and 'YTD' in value"

Comment: @Hass sorry for that. fixed that too

Comment: Thanks @Tomeriko, that works now. So how do i get it to return the column index number so i can use it to read data of that column. For instance, the column with the first YTD values is "3". 
I will ;ike to use the column number in the following code:
```
ff_sheet1.cell(row=insert_col + start_row, column= header['YTD_OT'], value=report_sheet1.cell(row=i + 7, column=col).value)
```

Comment: @Hass Can you explain what you're trying to get there? Is not very clear. you didn't define `i` and using cols to indicate the row...

Comment: @Tomeriko, See the code as modified to include "i". 
So i want to extract all the rows of data for the first column with "YTD". But instead of just using column index number, i want to use "col" as a placeholder for the corresponding column number with the word "YTD" so as to use for future operations because the excel file with change and the "YTD" columns will move.

Comment: I still don't get it @Hass. My code returns the column with the 'YTD' so you can then do with it whatever you want. If the file changes, you will have to run this every time to check again where that column is...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I want to find the corresponding column numbers for future use, for instance, in the case where i want extract the march column, then it's just a matter of subtracting 1 from that YTD col index.